# SwiftUI - How to create @FetchRequest with NSPredicate for the String and Date objects

Tags: swiftui, core-data

I am trying to create @FetchRequest to get list of items which name contains “bill” and transaction dates are >= “2023-01-29” and transaction dates are =< “2023-08-29” using following @Fetchrequest but nothing being displayed in the view. It seems that NSpredicate transaction date logics are incorrect.

```
@FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: [], predicate: NSPredicate(format: "(name CONTAINS[cd] 'bill') AND (transactionDate >= 2023-01-29) AND (transactionDate =< 2023-08-29)")) var lists: FetchedResults<Expense>
```

For the reference the name is String type and transactionDate is Date type.

Appreciate your helps.Thanks

Comment: Hi @ Sweeper. I checked the link and I don't know how to create such NSPredicate request inside the view. Could you please help. Thanks

Comment: How do you store the date, as Date or String?

Comment: Hi @Joakim Danielson. It stored as Date. Thanks

Comment: Then the linked question should help. As for creating such predicate there isn’t enough information in the question and there are plenty of questions here on SO and articles to help you with that.